# How to make a MIDI keyboard to work wirelessly with a Mac mini?

Tags: midi, midi-controller-keyboard, garage-band

I recently purchased a M-Audio Oxygen 49 MKIV MIDI keyboard for my 14 year old son and we connect it to our Mac mini and it works fine.  Is there something I can buy to make the keyboard wireless?  The goal is to keep it on a stand somewhat nearby the computer but without the wire running from the keyboard to the mac-mini computer. Any guidance greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try using some sort of a Bluetooth or Wireless MIDI adapter.

**For example:** https://9to5mac.com/2015/08/09/logic-pros-midi-wireless-bluetooth-puc/

The one used in the article is: https://www.zivix.co/

I **haven't** used one of those before so I can't tell how good they are.

Comment: Thanks for the reference to the puc device.  I wish it was in the $50 range instead of $100 - I Paid $229 for the keyboard - I'm surprised there isn't more wireless MIDI offerings.  I understand the fear of latency - but it seems like so many other wireless technologies for musicians have solved that.